# jQuery does not run

Tags: php, regex

Everything is ok in my code but jQuery does not affect the code at all. I have `ascss.css` and other file that I have include and all of them work but this animation `(fadeIn)` does not

```
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$document.ready(function(){//this code does not run
    $(".btn").submit(function(){
        $(".find").fadeIn(3000);        
        });

    });
</script>
</head>    
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="searchFile.php">
<table>
  <tr><br>
    <td >id :</td>
    <td><input name="id" type="text" maxlength="40" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">
    <input name="search" type="submit" value="search" class="btn"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['id']) and !empty($_POST['id']) and strlen($_POST['id'])==10)
{
    require_once("staticfileread.php");
    $s=staticfileread::search($_POST['id']);
    echo "<br><br><div class='find'>$s</div>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok thanks i have done what u say now what should i do to have this div appear by submition

Answer (score 1):

First: `$document` is undeclared, so you'll throw a reference error.

`$document.ready(someFunction)` should be `$(document).ready(someFunction)`, or the short hand: `$(someFunction)`.

Second: Submit events fire on *forms* not submit buttons.

Third: Even if the event handler was called, it is entirely possible that the form would finish submitting and a new page load before the content you were fading in had appeared.

Fourth: You only show `$(".find")` *after* the new page has loaded anyway, and it appears to be visible by default so there is nothing for it to fade in from.

Comment: ok thanks i have done what u say now what should i do to have this div appear by submition

Answer (score 0):

```
$document.ready(function() {
// Should be:
$(document).ready(function() {
```

When that is said; You can shorten the `.ready` function down to:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  // Same as $(document).ready(function() {});
});
```

Also note that you properly want to change:

```
$(".btn").submit(function() { ...
// Buttons doesn't emit a submit event, but forms do:
$("#form1").submit(function() { ...
```

Comment: You can shorten the `ready()` function down to simply `$( /* code here */ );` https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @Jonathan I know, I simply snuck in a way to make sure `$` refers to `jQuery`

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

1. `$document` should be `$(document)`
2. The `submit()` listener can only be bound to `<form>` elements. It should be `$("#form1").submit()`.

Answer (score 0):

in your code jquery code need to start like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // need to write your code here
});
```

check it once..